# How to convert a tf.estimator to a keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

In package `tf.estimator`, there's a lot of defined estimators. I want to use them in Keras.

I checked TF docs, there's only one converting method that could convert `keras. Model` to `tf. estimator`, but no way to convert from `estimator` to `Model`.

For example, if we want to convert the following estimator:

```
tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedRegressor
```

How could it be converted into Keras Model?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot because estimators can run arbitrary code in their `model_fn` functions and Keras models must be much more structured, whether sequential or functional they must consist of layers, basically.

A Keras model is a very specific type of object that can therefore be easily wrapped and plugged into other abstractions.

Estimators are based on arbitrary Python code with arbitrary control flow and so it's quite tricky to force any structure onto them.

Estimators support 3 modes - train, eval and predict. Each of these could in theory have completely independent flows, with different weights, architectures etc. This is almost unthinkable in Keras and would essentially amount to 3 separate models.

Keras, in contrast, supports 2 modes - train and test (which is necessary for things like Dropout and Regularisation).